# New error during set_labels in pandas 0.19.2: ValueError: Unequal label lengths

Tags: pandas

After upgrading from Pandas 0.18.1 to 0.19.2, I am getting the following error when I try to add new levels and labels to my dataframe. Any idea what the problem is?

```
print index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'1', u'2'], [u'nextLevel']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
           names=[u'segment..ASRinfo..supportedUtt', u'label'])

print levels

[['1', '2', 'Total'], ['nextLevel']]

print labels

[[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0]]

index = index.set_levels(levels)
print index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Supported', u'Unsupported', u'Total'], [u'nextLevel']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
           names=[u'segment..ASRinfo..supportedUtt', u'label'])

    index = index.set_labels(labels)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f6fb11fbbb3a> in <module>()
    288 
    289 # Initialize dfplot
--> 290 slice_data()
    291 
    292 if len(resultList)==1:

<ipython-input-11-f6fb11fbbb3a> in slice_data(*args)
     71     index = index.set_levels(levels)
     72     print index
---> 73     index = index.set_labels(labels)
     74     data_slice = data_slice.reindex(index)
     75 

/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.pyc in set_labels(self, labels, level, inplace, verify_integrity)
    350             idx = self._shallow_copy()
    351         idx._reset_identity()
--> 352         idx._set_labels(labels, level=level, verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
    353         if not inplace:
    354             return idx

/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.pyc in _set_labels(self, labels, level, copy, validate, verify_integrity)
    285 
    286         if verify_integrity:
--> 287             self._verify_integrity(labels=new_labels)
    288 
    289         self._labels = new_labels

/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.pyc in _verify_integrity(self, labels, levels)
    145             if len(label) != label_length:
    146                 raise ValueError("Unequal label lengths: %s" %
--> 147                                  ([len(lab) for lab in labels]))
    148             if len(label) and label.max() >= len(level):
    149                 raise ValueError("On level %d, label max (%d) >= length of"

ValueError: Unequal label lengths: [3, 3]
```

I'm wondering if it's a bug in the new pandas code. Perhaps self.labels[0] should be labels[0]?

```
def _verify_integrity(self, labels=None, levels=None):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    labels : optional list
        Labels to check for validity. Defaults to current labels.
    levels : optional list
        Levels to check for validity. Defaults to current levels.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        * if length of levels and labels don't match or any label would
        exceed level bounds
    """
    # NOTE: Currently does not check, among other things, that cached
    # nlevels matches nor that sortorder matches actually sortorder.
    labels = labels or self.labels
    levels = levels or self.levels

    if len(levels) != len(labels):
        raise ValueError("Length of levels and labels must match. NOTE:"
                         " this index is in an inconsistent state.")
    label_length = len(self.labels[0])
    for i, (level, label) in enumerate(zip(levels, labels)):
        if len(label) != label_length:
            raise ValueError("Unequal label lengths: %s" %
                             ([len(lab) for lab in labels]))
        if len(label) and label.max() >= len(level):
            raise ValueError("On level %d, label max (%d) >= length of"
                             " level  (%d). NOTE: this index is in an"
                             " inconsistent state" % (i, label.max(),
                                                      len(level)))
```

Comment: It does look like everything past `labels = labels or self.labels;
    levels = levels or self.levels` should use just `labels` or `levels`

Comment: Yes, I agree. If you look back at previous versions of the pandas code, like 0.18.1, they set labels and levels like this:
    `labels, levels = self.labels, self.levels`
But when they updated the labels and levels definition in this new code, they didn't update the references everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my fix and it worked! I submitted a bug to Pandas: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15157

Comment: You should probably follow the very detailed instructions on how to submit a bug report.

Comment: I don't think this works as if this index is part of a DataFrame then you will get an error when trying to use that DataFrame. It doesn't automatically fill the actual data associated with the new rows with missing values. This is what `reindex` is for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its a bug - I suppose Pandas could replace all the extra indexes with missing values doing it your way but I think you should use `reindex`

```
df.reindex(index2)

index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'1', u'2'], [u'nextLevel']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
           names=[u'segment..ASRinfo..supportedUtt', u'label'])

index2 = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['1', '2', 'Total'], ['nextLevel']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0]],
           names=[u'segment..ASRinfo..supportedUtt', u'label'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. What's the best way to construct index2 from index?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Pandas, and I found the documentation on MultiIndexing difficult to adapt to solving my own problem. Basically, I want to add some extra rows. This is the solution I came up with. There is probably a much better way to do it. Feel free to share if you'd like.

```
groupbyColumns = ['label0', 'label1']
data_slice = dataframe.groupby(by=groupbyColumns).sum()

index = data_slice.index

levels = list()
for levelIter in range(len(data_slice.index.levels)):
    levels.append([x for x in data_slice.index.levels[levelIter]])
levels[0].append('Total')
if len(resultList)==2:
    levels[-1].append('Difference')
    addIndexCountForDifferenceRow = 1
else:
    addIndexCountForDifferenceRow = 0

# Create new indexing sequence since we are adding Total (and Difference if doing comparison) rows
labels = list()
for labelIter in range(len(data_slice.index.labels)):
    labels.append(list())
if len(data_slice.index.labels)==2:
    labels0 = [x for x in data_slice.index.labels[0]]
    labels1 = [x for x in data_slice.index.labels[1]]
    for iter0 in range(max(labels0)+2):
        for iter1 in range(max(labels1)+1+addIndexCountForDifferenceRow):
            labels[0].append(iter0)
            labels[1].append(iter1)
if len(data_slice.index.labels)==3:
    labels0 = [x for x in data_slice.index.labels[0]]
    labels1 = [x for x in data_slice.index.labels[1]]
    labels2 = [x for x in data_slice.index.labels[2]]
    for iter0 in range(max(labels0)+2):
        for iter1 in range(max(labels1)+1):
            for iter2 in range(max(labels2)+1+addIndexCountForDifferenceRow):
                labels[0].append(iter0)
                labels[1].append(iter1)
                labels[2].append(iter2)

index = index.set_levels(levels)
index = index.set_labels(labels)
data_slice = data_slice.reindex(index)
```